# Depth estimation using phase shifted sine waves

Tags: phase, 3d, computer-graphics

For 3 phase shifted sine waves using the projected pattern: I = sin(x + δi) where δ ∈ [-2pi/3, 0, +2pi/3] which is then projected onto a scene. The resulting image is captured with a camera. I am using the method mentioned below as *Robust sine patterns*:
[image]

I have the following questions:

1. From what I understand, phi (obtained using inverse tangent) provides reconstructed 3D position (correct me if I am wrong)? What is confusing for me is that phi is a single scalar value. How does it provide 3D position(s)? What am I missing?
2. Ld (direct component) and Lg (global component) can help get different representations of the acquired scene?
3. How can I get depth estimation using these 3 phase shifted sinusoids?

Comment: Hi! Your question is missing some context: a reference to the original work you are trying to reproduce; the hardware setup assumed (several proyectors, or several cameras?); etc. Also, what have you tried and researched so far.